# OpenMP "master" for file I/O

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to parallelize the following function with OpenMP. If I use `#pragma omp parallel for private(dbf,t_tmp)` I got an BAD_EXEC while reading the database file. The `PreFilter` is  the computational most intensive task which should be parallelized. The optimal case would be one master thread for IO and slaves for the `PreFilter`. Is this possible with OpenMP or should I use pthreads?

```
for(int it=1; it <= dbfiles->size(); ++it) 
{
    ...

    dbf = openFILE(db_result->db_name,(char *)&id);
    ...
    readHMMFile(dbf,db_result->db_name,filename,t_tmp[curr_index],start_pos);   
    if(curr_index==0){ // modulo 4 ==0
          t_vec[bin]->MapFourHMMsToHMM4(t_tmp[0],t_tmp[1],t_tmp[2],t_tmp[3]);
          PreFilter(q_vec,t_vec[bin]);
    }
    fclose(dbf);
}
```

Comment: It's kind of difficult to say what is going on. What is `curr_index` and `start_pos`, and `t_tmp`? They probably have something to do with `it`, but what? Show us all the code. Also: Why are you opening and closing a file every time in a loop?

Comment: Looks like he is reading file names from a database and then processing each of those files. I would suggest that as many private variables as possible are decalred in the inner scope instead of being declared outside and then privatised with the `private` clause. BTW, this is tagged C but looks more like C++.

Comment: @ArjunShankar Hristo described it right. The loop iterates over a list of database row identifiers. Each of these keys will be read into one HMM object with readHMMFile. Four of these (t_tmp is a HMM array) will be processed in PreFilter. Curr_index is incremented in every iteration and if curr_index%4==0 than PreFilter will be called.  I have to close the database because the database api works in that way.